# Injecting one of the two @PersistenceContext

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

Consider having two entity manager factories:

```
<bean id="writeEntityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">...</bean>
<bean id="readOnlyEntityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">...</bean>
```

Then I want to have two Beans to which I would inject the correct persistence context:

```
<bean id="readOnlyManager" class="..MyDatabaseManager">
<bean id="writeManager" class="..MyDatabaseManager">
```

The bean would look something like:

```
public class MyDatabaseManager {

    private javax.persistence.EntityManager em;

    public EntityManager(javax.persistence.EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }
    ...
}
```

This obviously doesn't work, because EntityManager is not a bean and cannot be injected in this way:

```
No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

How can I qualify correct EntityManager in the bean? I used to use `@PersistenceContext` annotation, but this is not usable as I need to inject it.

How can I specify the PersistenceContext for such Bean?

UPDATE: My question is how to inject PersistenceContext with qualifier via XML, not via annotation.

Comment: You could inject the EntityManagerFactory

Comment: Is that a good idea? Only way to get enitymanager is then via `emFactory.getNativeEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager()` which create a new one. I am not sure whether it is a good idea to create new one?

Comment: @Vojtěch here is in details http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/how-to-setup-multiple-data-sources-with-spring-and-jpa/

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are using spring in order to manage transactions what I would do is 2 different transaction managers and then in my services i would use the most appropriate transaction manager like this:

**Configuration section**

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean writeEntityManagerFactory() {

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    //Your configuration here
    return factory;
}

@Bean(name={"writeTx"})
public PlatformTransactionManager writeTransactionManager() {

    JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(writeEntityManagerFactory().getObject());
    return txManager;
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean readEntityManagerFactory() {

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    //Your configuration here
    return factory;
}

@Bean(name={"readTx"})
public PlatformTransactionManager readTransactionManager() {

    JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(readEntityManagerFactory().getObject());
    return txManager;
}
```

**Service layer**

```
@Transactional(value="readTx")
public List<Object> read(){
    //Your read code here
}

@Transactional(value="writeTx")
public void write(){
    //Your write code here
}
```

**UPDATED ANSWER**
I misunderstood the question.

In your configuration class you can define:

```
@Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean writeEntityManagerFactory() {

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em  = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "models" });
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(hibProps());
        em.setPersistenceUnitName("writer");
        return em;
    }
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean readEntityManagerFactory() {

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em  = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "models" });
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(hibProps());
        em.setPersistenceUnitName("reader");
        return em;
    }
```

Please see the `PersistenceUnitName` values

Then you can injecting them by doing:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="writer")
private EntityManager emWriter;

@PersistenceContext(unitName="reader")
private EntityManager emReader;
```

I just tested it and all worked pretty good

Angelo

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I am not worried about TransactionManager, but PersistenceContext.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer, but again: I cannot insert them with annotation `@PersistenceContext` as I want to inject it via XML configuration. Same issue as with the other answer.

Comment: Yep, persitence unit name is what exactly needed in case multiple ems are declared

Answer (score 1):

persistence.xml (2 persistence unit for 2 different entitymanager, based on your persistence provider here i ma using HibernatePersistence)

```
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
   <persistence-unit name="pu1">
      <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
   </persistence-unit>

   <persistence-unit name="pu2">
      <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
   </persistence-unit>   
</persistence>
```

Make sure you are assigning the persistence-unit to entity manager using property persistenceUnitName

```
    <bean id="writeEntityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath: of yout persistence xml" />
            <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="pu1" />  
             .....other configuration of em..  
    </bean>
```

same for other em.

Now, use constructor injection for MyDatabaseManager to inject EntityManager (using qualifier name ex. writeEntityManagerFactory )

```
<bean id="mdm" class="MyDatabaseManager">
     <constructor-arg ref = "writeEntityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: I already clarified I need to define the qualifier in the XML, not in the code via annotation: `How can I qualify correct EntityManager in the bean? I used to use @PersistenceContext annotation, but this is not usable as I need to inject it.`

Comment: That is still not enough - how do you get the entitymanager from the factory without creating a new one? I want to use the one which has already been created.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are trying to inject an entityManager into your manager class

```
public class MyDatabaseManager {

// where you need to qualify your injection    
private javax.persistence.EntityManager em;

    public EntityManager(javax.persistence.EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }
    ...
}
```

here are the working codes for my project

1. Persistence.xml in META-INF folder

   ```
    <persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
        <persistence-unit name="PERSISTENCE_UNIT_T" transaction-type="JTA">
            <provider>foo.bar.PersistenceProvider</provider>
            <jta-data-source>jdbc/DB2</jta-data-source>

        </persistence-unit>

         <persistence-unit name="PERSISTENCE_UNIT_P" transaction-type="JTA">
            <provider>foo.bar.PersistenceProvider</provider>
            <jta-data-source>jdbc/DB2</jta-data-source>

        </persistence-unit> 
    </persistence>
   ```
2. Qualifier interface class SelectDataSource

> ```
>  @Qualifier
>     @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
>     @Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD })
>     public @interface SelectDataSource{}
> ```

3. EntityManager class

   public class EntityManager {

   ```
        public EntityManager() {
        }

        @Inject
        @SelectDataSource
        private EntityManager entityManager;

        // other entity manager methods

    }
   ```
4. Entity Manager Provider class to provide persistence unit based on context

   public class EntityManagerProvider {

   ```
        @PersistenceContext(unitName = "PERSISTENCE_UNIT_T")
        private EntityManager entityManagerT;

        @PersistenceContext(unitName = "PERSISTENCE_UNIT_P")
        private EntityManager entityManagerP;


        @Produces
        @SelectDataSource
        EntityManager createEntityManager(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {

            if (System.ENV.equalsIgnoreCase("p")) {
                if (entityManagerP != null) {

                    return entityManagerP;
                }
            }

            return entityManagerT;
        }

    }
   ```

**then the EntityManager class can be injected to wherever you like with `@Inject`**

Below is a nice post on how to use Context Dependency Injection to create managed entity manager
https://www.sitepoint.com/cdi-weld-inject-jpa-hibernate-entity-managers/#usingaproducermethod